# What is the difference between Title and TitleResource

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, list-item, localization

If I am localizing SharePoint a lot of Fields have 2 public properties:

- `Title`
- `TitleResource`

What is the difference between them?

Currently I am localizing a Field with this piece of code:

```
foreach (SPLanguage lang in InstalledLanguages)
{
    SPField field = CurrentList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldName);
    field.Title = Utility.GetSharePointResource(InternalListName, FieldName, (uint)lang.LCID);
    field.Update(true);
    field.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(new CultureInfo(lang.LCID), Utility.GetSharePointResource(InternalListName, FieldName, (uint)lang.LCID));
    field.TitleResource.Update();
}
```

As you can see, I am setting both values. Could I get away with only setting the `Title` or the `TitleResource` property?

Answer (score 2):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.titleresource.aspx) TitleResource is the source for Title property. Usually, setting Title property sets the value for the current culture. To set the Title value for multiple culture we need to use TitleResource.